# Is it possible to create a single global government, economy and currency

Tags: economy, government, currency

I understand that this might be hard to answer but in a scenario where every action results in a positive outcome and everything needed gets the thumbs up and goes well (spoiler: this never happens) what would be needed to create a single global government with a single monarch, president, dictator or ruler and a single global currency & economy?

Would revolutions of this magnitude be as bad as *"regular"* revolutions or would it be worse?

Comment: This belongs on worldbuilding.se

Comment: @blip I'm asking what is needed to achieve this (if even possible) politically & economically in real life and not in an imaginary world.

Comment: worldbuilding.se looks like a great site thanks for introducing it to me.

Comment: @Mango, The future IS an imaginary world.

Comment: See Dror's [The Capacity to Govern](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Capacity-Govern-Report-Club-Rome/dp/0714683140) (2001) - One reviewer writes: "Yehezkel Dror's book "The Capacity to Govern" is a Club of Rome report that asks the philosophical question, is the world really ready for global government and if so, how would they go about enacting it? Dror deduces that global government could succeed if more benevolent approaches were taken such as "empowering the people with public affairs enlightenment," which means educating the masses. ..."

Comment: I don't thing that Sweden and Saudi Arabia can form a government by other means than conquer. Also consider that in 1950 3 out of 4 most populous countries in the world had awful governments: India, China and USSR. No one can guarantee that our world president would be someone like Eisenhower.

Comment: Sure, as long as aliens threaten to invade Earth. Then we could finally point to a foreigner and say 'well, at least he's not from Andromeda'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of a World Government is pretty old and has already been discussed by many philosophers and politicians.

**Theoretical benefits of this concept:**

- Humanity would no longer be split
- Worldwide peace & no military needed
- Better wealth, food, and medical distribution
- One economy & currency
- ....

**Requirements:**

To establish this system a global crisis is needed. This could be a world wide economic crash, a great war or a humanitarian disaster. The suffering of people must be high. Media and the current governments need to cooperate to convince the citizen. Otherwise it's impossible to change the system. Only agony makes the people forget their national pride.

**What's needed to keep this state ?**

One executive, legislature, judiciary and constitution. There will be one main government which consits of representatives of old governments and economy. The administration is divided between several federal states which are subordinated to the main government. The federal states have a limited power to act. They are mainly for law execution and management. The currency system will be renewed and the economy more regulated. There will be more monitoring of citizens to measure the dissatisfaction of the people to avoid riots.

**Conclusion**

A World Government is possible. The consequences before it is established are particularly bad for the citizen. To keep the system all lose some freedom to obtain long-term peace.

That's not my opinion what should happen. It's just a szenario.